# New update application android?

Tags: android, dialog, updates

What is the best way to let the users know that I have an update. I had seen once an application with update dialog but I really don't know how they did it. Can someone guide me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess they either use [unofficial android market api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) to get the latest app version or they pull own server which knows about updates.

Answer (score 0):

Maby let your application query an internet server on startup :) Pretty straightforward but it will do just fine.